# Can't stop my navigation menu from overlapping YouTube video iframe

Tags: jquery, css

I've been searching for a solution to this problem only to find solutions for the opposite problem (people trying to get their video content to stop covering their nav menus).

I'm using a jQuery lightbox clone plugin--"prettyPhoto" (http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyphoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/).

I've tried setting the wmode for the video to both opaque and transparent, and I've tried setting a very high z-value for the iframe in both modes without any luck at all.

I can provide code if needed but I feel as though there's probably an easy fix for this that I'm just completely missing.

Comment: give us a code, css and html. Z-index should help

Comment: Do both elements have a position other than static?